# Adding a network laser jet via ipp to a windows workstation

Tags: networking, printing, printer, network-printer, hp-laserjet

My company has an HP Color LaserJet MFP E77822 on the network.  Not attached to a print server or anything. Just on the network.

And I can add it to my Windows workstation just fine via the "add printer using tcp/ip address or hostname" option in Windows and connecting by just a standard tcp/ip port. Printing works fine when I do this.

But now we're being told we'll need to connect via IPP (actually IPPS but I'm starting with IPP first to make sure I can connect to it at all without certificate issues).

And every time I try to add, I get an error message "Windows couldn't connect to the printer. Check the printer name and try again."
[image]

I'm using the "select a shared printer by name" option as described here https://zedt.eu/tech/windows/installing-an-ipp-printer-in-windows-10/

I'm using names like "http://" and "http:///ipp"  .    Perhaps I'm not using the right path there?  Or should I not be using "select a shared printer by name" method to add an IPP printer?

If I choose to add by IP or Host name using an address like above, it never seems to connect either. It goes through the motions and I select a driver. But sending things to the printer just seems to have things go the queue in the "printing" state but nothing happens.

IPP/IPPS is enabled on the printer. And I have installed the IPP print client and server on my workstation. I think there's a concept I'm fundamentally not understanding about this.

Comment: http://10.43.16.233:[port]/printername

Comment: where do you get the name? I grab the host name out of the networking section of the config websiteon the device (which I can reach just fine) but I get the same results.

Comment: Try using /net view [serverIP]

Comment: it's not connected to a print server. But feeding the printers address to net view brings up a network path as not found.  I can ping the ip fine

Comment: Check this page: https://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/InstallingIPPSPrinters

Comment: Yeah that’s pretty much what I described I was doing in the description that does not work